# EC2 Image Builder - sharing produced AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, ec2-ami

I'm trying to configure EC2 Image Builder for the first time using Terraform. I'm running the pipeline inside a CI/CD account and the image is used from the production and staging accounts. In other words, the AMI produced should be shared to these two accounts. My problem is that the produced images aren't shared and I can't locate in the Terraform docs how this should be done.

The relevant Terraform code is:

```
data "aws_imagebuilder_component" "cloudwatch" {
  arn = "arn:aws:imagebuilder:${data.aws_region.current.name}:aws:component/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-linux/1.0.1"
}

data "aws_imagebuilder_component" "codedeploy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:imagebuilder:${data.aws_region.current.name}:aws:component/aws-codedeploy-agent-linux/1.0.2"
}

resource "aws_imagebuilder_component" "yum" {
  data = yamlencode({
    phases = [{
      name = "build"
      steps = [{
        name   = "InstallSoftware"
        action = "ExecuteBash"
        inputs = {
          commands = [
            "yum update -y",
            "yum install -y java-17-amazon-corretto-headless",
            "amazon-linux-extras install -y BCC",
            "yum install -y bpftrace collectd"
          ]
        }
      }]
    }]
    schemaVersion = 1.0
  })
  name     = "proxy-runtime"
  platform = "Linux"
  version  = "0.0.1"
}

resource "aws_imagebuilder_image_recipe" "proxy-x86_64" {
  block_device_mapping {
    device_name = "/dev/xvdb"

    ebs {
      delete_on_termination = true
      volume_size           = 10
      volume_type           = "gp2"
    }
  }

  component {
    component_arn = data.aws_imagebuilder_component.cloudwatch.arn
  }

  component {
    component_arn = data.aws_imagebuilder_component.codedeploy.arn
  }

  component {
    component_arn = aws_imagebuilder_component.yum.arn
  }

  name         = "proxy-x86_64-gp2"
  parent_image = "arn:aws:imagebuilder:${data.aws_region.current.name}:aws:image/amazon-linux-2-x86/x.x.x"
  version      = "0.0.1"
}

resource "aws_imagebuilder_distribution_configuration" "proxy-x86_64" {
  name = "proxy"

  distribution {
    ami_distribution_configuration {
      name = "proxy-x86_64-{{ imagebuilder:buildDate }}"

      launch_permission {
        user_ids = ["1234567890", "0987654321"]
      }
      target_account_ids = ["1234567890", "0987654321"]
    }

    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_imagebuilder_infrastructure_configuration" "proxy-x86_64" {
  description                   = "Proxy AMI builder infra"
  instance_profile_name         = aws_iam_instance_profile.instance.name
  instance_types                = ["t3.small", "t3.medium"]
  name                          = "proxy-x86_64-ami-builder"
  security_group_ids            = [aws_security_group.builder.id]
  subnet_id                     = data.aws_subnet.default.id
  terminate_instance_on_failure = true

  logging {
    s3_logs {
      s3_bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.logs.bucket
      s3_key_prefix  = "proxy-ec2-builder-logs"
    }
  }

 lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_imagebuilder_image_pipeline" "proxy-x86_64" {
  image_recipe_arn                 = aws_imagebuilder_image_recipe.proxy-x86_64.arn
  infrastructure_configuration_arn = aws_imagebuilder_infrastructure_configuration.proxy-x86_64.arn
  distribution_configuration_arn   = aws_imagebuilder_distribution_configuration.proxy-x86_64.arn
  name                             = "proxy-x86_64"
}
```

My guess has been that the `aws_imagebuilder_distribution_configuration` resource is used to set the permissions on the produced AMIs. However, the two settings I've tried to use there doesn't seem to add my two accounts to the list of accounts that the AMI is shared with. Anyone know how the produced AMIs can be configured to be automatically shared with some accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you need the `ec2:ModifyImageAttribute` IAM permission in the instance profile of the infrastructure configuration. This wasn't clearly stated anywhere in the manual and without it the pipeline execution finishes without error, even though it's unable to modify the AMI sharing permissions.

Checking out what API function is used to modify the sharing permissions and adding that function to the instance role fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
resource "aws_ami_launch_permission" "this" {
  image_id   = "image_id"
  account_id = "account_id"
}
```

See [ami_launch_permission](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ami_launch_permission) for further reference